# How to use PowerShell to change password in .ini file

Tags: powershell, scripting, ini

I am trying to change the password in a .ini file. The password is stored as plain text after the string  "Password=". The .ini file is stored in C:\windows\SysWOW64\Folder

How could I use Powershell to change the value of the password to a new password.

I cannot use find and replace since the current password is the same as the username.

If anyone has any ideas and would like to share I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There are a couple things you could do for this yes like using `Get-Content` and maybe a regex match and replace. Try something and if you get stuck on something specific edit your question and we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: I didnt develop the application nor do i have the abilty to change the source code but i agree the password should not be put in plain text.  I am just responsible for changing the password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$newpw = "newpw"
(get-content .\blah.ini) -replace "password=(\w+)", "password=$newpw" | Out-File .\blah.ini
```